# $f_x(x,y)=f_y(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \iff f(x,y)=f(0,x+y)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable. I want to prove: $f_x(x,y)=f_y(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \iff f(x,y)=f(0,x+y)$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

For this <= direction I have to derivate f and calculate $f_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$, but I'm not sure how to calculate $f_x(0,x+y)$ for example. What is $f_x(0,x+y)$?.

How to prove this => direction? Maybe I have to integrate, but I don't know how to do it exactly here:(

Answer (score 3):

Fix a certain $(x,y)$ and consider the function $$w(\lambda) = f(y-\lambda , x+\lambda)$$

Then by the chain rule $$w'(\lambda) = -f_x(y-\lambda,x+\lambda)+f_y(y-\lambda,x+\lambda) = 0$$
by the condition you specify. Therefore $w$ is constant, and for example $$f(x,y) = \underbrace{w(0) = w(y)}_{w \text{ const.}} = f(0,x+y)$$
as desired.

For more on this, look up information on the *transport equation*. It is a typical example of a linear partial differential equation and there are a multitude of ways of understanding it and solving it; this has been only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is a solution to the partial differential equation
$$
u_x-u_y=0,
$$
so it can be written in the form $$
f(x,y)=g(x+y),
$$
for some function $g$, and the claim follows.

Comment: thank you! But I have problems to understand it. I know nothing about partial differential equations. Why is f(x,y)=g(x+y) for some g?

Comment: Well can you prove that $f$ is constant on lines $x+y=c$. Try to take derivative along this line  and prove that it is zero.